# how to get current date in arduino without interfacing with pc?

Tags: arduino

I want to place my kit independently without interfacing without PC,but it needs to know the current date.please do help with your answers.

Comment: How accurate do you need the time or date to be?

Comment: Please provide more information, and be specific. Go and re-read the rules, because this question is breaking the rules by not being specific enough. We have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

You've got a couple options:

- Use a GPS. This is relatively straightforward and *very* accurate. Most GPS units require no configuration, and will output an NMEA data stream via a serial connection, from which you can extract date/time. However, power consumption and start-up time may be unpalatable. Adding an RTC and only retrieving time occasionally solves this.
- Use a network device that connects to a local network via Ethernet or WiFi, and retrieves the time via NTP or even an HTTP query to any server that reports time in the request. There are many Ethernet and WiFi shields that are designed for the Arduino.
- Build/buy a [WWVB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WWVB) receiver.

Or ditch the Arduino and buy a board that has built-in WiFi (NodeMCU is very easy to use, and retrieving time via HTTP is dead simple).

Answer (score 0):

You can add an RTC module(DS1307) to the Arduino from which you can get the exact time & date.